# Overriding bootstrap data-toggle=“dropdown”

Tags: jquery, html

Hey I have a problem how to trigger `data-toggle="dropdown"` only in small devices ( less than 767px ), boostrap trigger it from 991px width, I am trying just update the value or remove it but nothing happens so I cant do anything with `data-toggle="dropdown"` ? Any advice welcomed

```
$("a").data("toggle", "update");
$("a").removeData("toggle");

<!-- this is in my html -->
<a href="/Samohyl/volkswagen/modely" class="dropdown-toggle">
    Volkswagen
</a>

<!-- and this happens on 991px and less (bootstrap add data-toggle but I would need add it after 767px ) -->
<a href="/Samohyl/volkswagen/modely" class=dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Volkswagen
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**1st:** wrap your code in `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //$("a[data-toggle]").attr("data-toggle", "update");
   $("a[data-toggle]").removeAttr("data-toggle");
})
```

**2nd:** you can use `$(window).width()` to determine the width you want

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($(window).width() < 767){
     $("a[data-toggle]").removeAttr("data-toggle");
   }
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a[data-toggle]").attr("data-toggle", "update");
  //$("a[data-toggle]").removeAttr("data-toggle");
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- this is in my html -->
<a href="/Samohyl/volkswagen/modely" class="dropdown-toggle">
    Volkswagen
</a>

<!-- and this happens on 991px and less (bootstrap add data-toggle but I would need add it after 767px ) -->
<a href="/Samohyl/volkswagen/modely" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Volkswagen
</a>
```

Comment: @george I updaed my answer with snippet .. please take a look at it

Comment: mm interesting even this not works btw maybe bootstrap´s data i cant overwrite or anything else

Comment: mm yes i tried add my own data-push="push" and overwrite to update and it works but bootstraps i cant wtf